# Buffer string() not equal string

Tags: json, string, http, testing, go

I try to test if my http handler is returning the right values inside the body.

This is my handler function

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    message := `{"status": "OK"}`
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(message); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
}
```

This is my test

```
func TestIndex(t *testing.T){

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
    }

    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(Index)

    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    expected := `"{"status": "OK"}"`

    if rr.Body.String() != expected {
    t.Errorf("handler returned unexpected body: got %v want %v",
        rr.Body.String(), expected)
    }
}
```

The result of the test is:

```
handlers_test.go:244: handler returned unexpected body: got "{\"status\": \"OK\"}"
     want {"status": "OK"}
```

I think the escaping of the " is because of the json Encode, but even if I change the expected to

```
expected := `"{\"status\": \"OK\"}"`
```

it does not work, than the result of the test is

```
handlers_test.go:244: handler returned unexpected body: got "{\"status\": \"OK\"}"
     want "{\"status\": \"OK\"}"
```

In the [docs](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=4388:4435#L178) I found something that json encode appends a newline character, but I did not manage to get the test working even with that information :-/

In advance, thanks for your help.

Comment: `expected := \`"{"status": "OK"}\`` this has an extra " before the {. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @Shinratensei: Thanks for the hint. Edited the snippet, but did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Yeah I know, it was just something that looked weird to me. Look at the answers, they know more about golang

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message you send:

```
message := `{"status": "OK"}`
```

Is already a valid JSON text, you don't need any further JSON encoding / processing on it. Just send it as-is:

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    message := `{"status": "OK"}`
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    io.WriteString(w, message)
}
```

Also note that if your response code is `http.StatusOK`, you don't need to set that explicitly, as that is the default if you don't set it.

And then simply expect the following response:

```
expected := `{"status": "OK"}`
```

**Explaining your original code:**

In your original code you JSON-marshaled a single `string` value, whose content was `{"status": "OK"}`. JSON encoding will quote this text into a valid JSON string (prefix quotation marks with a backslash), put inside quotes, and also appends a newline character. So this becomes the raw string:

```
expected := `"{\"status\": \"OK\"}"
`
```

Using this `expected` value, your test passes, but again, what you want is in the first part of this answer.

If you want to use an interpreted string literal to describe the `expected` value, this is how it could look like:

```
expected := "\"{\\\"status\\\": \\\"OK\\\"}\"\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reponse: changed the expected but got 
 handlers_test.go:244: handler returned unexpected body: got "{\"status\": \"OK\"}"
   want {\"status\": \"OK\"}

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for this test, but I got another where I had to use json.encode. I found a solution to the problem by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The linebreak was the problem. I managed to solve it with adding strings.TrimRight and cut if right off the string.

```
if strings.TrimRight(rr.Body.String(), "\n") != expected {
    t.Errorf("handler returned unexpected body: got %v want %v",
        rr.Body.String(), expected)
    }
```